# ASP.NET Core middleware redirect to another route

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an ASP.NET 6 Web API controller and it has two methods.

This is my code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Test")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Test()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("User")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> UserInfo()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a middleware component:

```
public class RequestResponseMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var req = context.Request;
        context.Response.Redirect("/weatherforecast/User",true,true);
         await _next(context);
     }
}
```

I used

```
https://localhost:7290/weatherforecast/Test?t=1675343945003&m=&k=sdf
```

to test it.

In the middleware, response can redirect to `/weatherforecast/User`, but it will fire 5 times. It means that the method `UserInfo()` will be invoked 5 times.

What's wrong with my code? And how to fix the problem?

----update----

mapping example.

```
{
    "Routes":[
        {
            "Controllor": "WeatherForecast",
            "Metods":[
                {
                    "Test": "User" 
                },
                {
                    "Weather": "Weather"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---- update2 ----

`context.Response.Redirect`
will invoke `WeatherForecast/ Test`1 time, and invoke `WeatherForecast/User`4 times.

---- update 3 ----

code
[code here](https://files.cnblogs.com/files/goldli/WebApplication1.zip?t=1675413694&download=true)

Answer (score 0):

You have to branch the pineline,or the next time you already redirected to `/weatherforecast/User` the middleware would redirect you to the same uri again

Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline-1)

For example:

```
app.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.Value.Contains("Test"), app =>
{    
  app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseMiddleware>();
});
```

Create a Class to bind the configration file:

```
public class RouteMap
    {
        public string Controllor { get; set; }
        public List<Dictionary<string,string>> Methods { get; set; }

    }
```

In program.cs:

```
var routemap=new List<RouteMap>();
app.Configuration.GetSection("Routes").Bind(routemap);


app.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.Check(routemap), app =>
{
    app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseMiddleware>();
});
```

Complete the extension method:

```
public static class Extension
    {
        public static bool Check(this PathString pathString,List<RouteMap> routeMaps)
        {
            bool exist=false;

            // you need to modify the logical here yourself to match the route

             var controllername= pathString.Value?.Split('/')[1];

             var methodname = pathString.Value?.Split('/')[2];


            foreach (RouteMap routeMap in routeMaps)
            {
                if (routeMap.Controllor == controllername)
                {
                   foreach(var methodmaps in routeMap.Methods)
                    {
                        if (methodmaps.ContainsKey(methodname))
                        {                           
                            exist =true;
                            break;                            
                        }                      
                    }
                    if (exist)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return exist;
        }
    }
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I don't want a hard code configuration likes  Test -> RequestResponseMiddleware  .  In fact, there is a configuration file. It contains Contrllor/Method -> Controlor/Method mappings.    I want to map the mappings from the file to invoke the currect Controllor/Method.

Comment: Would you show the example of your file and i'll update the answer

Comment: @Goldli Zh,
I've updated my answer,please check it

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  i will upload my code. and you can test my code. with you code , Method ```UserInfo``` will be invoked.  if you used a Debug.WriteLine("...") just as i did, you will find that , method ```Test``` would be fired 1 time , and ```UserInfo``` would be fired 4 times.

Comment: i'll try your codes next monday,in myh case,I added break point on each controller,and only User controller would be hit once,when redirected  from Test Controller

Answer (score 0):

i know what's wrong with my code . There is not a exist condition before redirect.
a solution likes

```
            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && context.Request.Path == "/weatherforecast/Test") 
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/weatherforecast/User", false);
            }
            else
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
```